# MongoD size of multiple nested arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection of poems. The document in the collection has the following structure:

```
{
"_id" : "Romeo and Juliet",
"acts" : [ 
    {
        "title" : "ACT I",
        "scenes" : [ 
            {
                "title" : "SCENE I. Verona. A public place.",
                "action" : [ 
                    {
                        "character" : "SAMPSON",
                        "says" : [ 
                            "Gregory, o' my word, we'll not carry coals."
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "character" : "GREGORY",
                        "says" : [ 
                            "No, for then we should be colliers."
                        ]
                    }, 
                    // ...
                    {
                        "character" : "GREGORY",
                        "says" : [ 
                            "To move is to stir; and to be valiant is to stand:", 
                            "therefore, if thou art moved, thou runn'st away."
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "character" : "SAMPSON",
                        "says" : [ 
                            "A dog of that house shall move me to stand: I will", 
                            "take the wall of any man or maid of Montague's."
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "character" : "GREGORY",
                        "says" : [ 
                            "That shows thee a weak slave; for the weakest goes", 
                            "to the wall."
                        ]
                    }
                    // ...
                ]
            }
            // ...
        ]
    }
    // ...
]}
```

I want to count number of acts and scenes for each poem.
I tried to do something like this, but the result is incorrect.

```
db.poems.aggregate([{$unwind:"$acts"}, {$unwind:"$acts.scenes"}, {$group: {_id: "$_id", pa: {$push: {poemAct:"$acts"}}, ps: {$push: {poemScenes:"$acts.scenes"}}}}, {$project: {numberOfActs: {$size: "$pa"}, numberOfScenes: {$size: "$ps"}}}]).pretty()
```

Help somebody, please :D

Comment: what is the format of expected output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try below aggregation. No `$unwind` required here.

[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) to output array with scenes sizes and [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to count the array values.

```
db.poems.aggregate({
  "$project":{
    "numberOfActs":{"$size":"$acts"},
    "numberOfScenes":{
      "$sum":{
        "$map":{
          "input":"$acts",
          "in":{"$size":"$$this.scenes"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
db.poems.find().forEach(function(poem) {
    var res = {};
    res._id = poem._id, 
    res.acts = poem.acts.length;
    res.scenes = poem.acts.scenes.length;
    printjson(res)
})
```